# Init datatable from page n instead of page 1

Tags: jquery, datatables

I would like to Init my datatable (jquery DataTables 1.10.15) from page n instead of page 1.
I read the doc and some post about stateSave but nothing helped me.
This is what I got from now :

```
    var table = jQuery('#tabcool')
    .DataTable( {
      // init table from page 4
    });
    table
      .order( [ 0, 'desc' ] )
      .page(4)
      .draw();
    });
```

But I don't know how to init from page 4 this table.
Thanks.

EDIT : I used  `.page(4)` method but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function your are looking for is function page( set )

see https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()

```
    var table = jQuery('#tabcool').DataTable();
    table
        .order( [ 0, 'desc' ] )
        .page(4)
        .draw('page');
      });
```

edit: I have also added an example here https://codepen.io/ji_in_coding/pen/mGdWrK

Comment: Thanks. I edited my initial question. Nothing happened.